# How to use an n-Tier design with a winforms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

I have a WinForms application that will heavily rely on EF6 to connect to a SQL Database file rather than an access database. First, I am basing this design on  [Entity Framework in Winforms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms); Second, uses the following N-Tier design: {Presentation Layer} <--> {DAL} <--> {Model}. My issue that I am running into is that when I try to specify the datasource on some of the form controls, VS'15 only wants to hit my model, bypassing the DAL completely.

What am I missing, or need to do to get EF6 to use my DAL rather than directly connecting to the Model?

Comment: This article isn't about *architecture*, it only shows a basic usage of Entity Framework. You also confuse what the model and DAL are/do - EF's model is **not** the model used by the application. The DAL will *load* the model and your forms will bind to this model. Finally n-Tier does *not* apply to desktop/UI design, it's used to split complex applications to separate, distributed layers. You should look into the MVC, MVP and MVVM patterns - MVVM is the best approach since it separates the DTOs (EF's entities) from the models used by different screens

Comment: Do you have a separate database server? Do your application install on multiple clients? How much is security important?

Comment: I actually found a solution here: [link](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/)